# Xceed.Words.NET table crossing a page break

Tags: c#, .net, libraries, docx, xceed

I'm looking for a way when I add a table by `document.InsertTable()` to trigger an action if the table cross a page boundary. I want to add a remark as the title of the table plus something like "Title of the table(***continuation***)".
I couldn't even find any property which contain the actual page number....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I close this question after understanding that nothing is possible with the free version of Xceed Words library. Anyway that shouldn't be really easy anyway because to my sense the render engine of word is responsible of managing the page break.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to trigget an action if a table spans more than one page.  However it is possible to check the pages at the start and end of the table.

For the start of the table

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
```

For the end of the table

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells.Count).Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
```

In the above I've used ActiveDocument In practice you'd use a variable returning a range.

You'd also likely want to simplify the lines by placing them within a With/End With using

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range

    my_first_page =.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    my_last_page = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

End With
```

Comment: I don't think your code is related to Xceed Words for .NET.

Comment: I saw the tag docx and that you were inserting a table so I assumed you were inserting a table into a word document.  Apologies if that isn't the case.